# How to create custom buffer from list of ints in Python

Tags: python

How can I create a binary buffer from a list of ints?
Suppose we know the list size on behalf.

```
buf = bytearray((n + 1) * 4)
parts = # this is list of ints line [10, 15, 34]
```

How to fill the buffer with the binary values of the numbers?

For this example, the list size is always the same and known (n=3 in this example).

The second part of my program will be able to read the bytes and parse them in the same way.

Comment: In which range are the integers? How many bytes per integer do you want to have? Do you want to encode them in little-endian or big-endian byte order?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question, but the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray say you can just pass an iterable of integers, e.g. `buf = bytearray(parts)` ... is that not what you want? And you don't specify the size to the constructor.